# Ubuntu Evolution POP3 send/receive deleted the files off of my server! How do I undelete (Get them back on)?

Tags: ubuntu, pop3, evolution

Actually did this with both my Hotmail and my Webmail.godaddy.com accounts. I now know how to tell it not to delete the emails in the future but can't seem to figure out how to replace the ones already deleted and now only available on the computer with my Evolution account on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're really wanting to do, if possible, is switch to IMAP instead of POP3.

If IMAP is available on your mail servers you could try this:

1. Set up a second account in Evolution connecting to your mail server using IMAP
2. Drag and drop the mails into the IMAP instance of the account.

That should copy them back to the mail server.  Personally I'd stick with IMAP instead of POP3 (I use IMAP for all my accounts) as it's more aimed at storing the mail on the server whereas POP3 is aimed at downloading the mails to the client computer.

Comment: Thanks, Matt! It worked--everything's back where it should be.:)